# Deformed 45 deg angle on outer wall

Tags: ultimaker-cura, filament, slicing

I have tried a couple different fixes but none worked, when watching the printer it looks like the head accelerates suddenly when printing that wall.  However, when looking at the gcode the acceleration appears to be the same everywhere.

down the middle of the pic you can see what I am talking about.  On the far left there is another 45 deg angle that printed just fine.

This is on a Anycubic Chiron using Cura 5.6.

[image: Photo]

- I have a Anycubic Chiron which I use together with Cura.
- I print in PLA at 210-215 °C.
- The print bed is set to 60 °C.
- I use a print cooling fan at 100 %.
- The layer height I set to 0.2 mm
- The line width 0.4 from the 0.4 mm nozzle.
- The printing speed is set to 50 mm/s for walls (outer walls are 35 mm/s) and 75 mm/s for infill.
- My retraction is 0.8 mm/off at 10 mm/s.

Comment: Hi Zorro and welcome. Your question is lacking detail and as such is hard to answer without knowing a couple of things about your printer setup. Please [edit] and fill in the [placeholders] in the template I added and then remove the leading `<!--` and trailing `-->` afterwards. This will turn it visible and help us help you find the actual problem.

Comment: That's a seam as far as I can tell

Answer (score 0):

These kinds of artifacts can arise in a lot of ways, and are really frustrating to deal with. From what I can tell, they're related to the "stalagmite" stringing you can get on travel with wet filament or insufficient retraction, and the basic mechanism seems to be material failing to come out of the nozzle when expected, then getting "pulled out" by surface tension or similar type forces starting upon hitting a slightly larger bump of material from the previous layer just below it.

It looks like you're having this problem right after travel/unretract to a starting point on the outer perimeter. If so, this could be a result of losing material during travel (especially likely if you're skipping retractions for travel within the infill region).

Another very likely cause is wet filament, making it so that it takes just a moment longer for the extrusion to start, due to getting past bubbly gunk or taking more energy to overcome the water stealing it for boiling or whatever. Drying your filament would be an easy thing you could do to check if this is the cause before spending lots of time on other possibilities.

Another cause for this sort of thing is using a line width narrower than your nozzle orifice. This allows the material to expand outward in the nozzle orifice before it really starts flowing out. I know you said you have an 0.4 mm nozzle, but if it's old or if you've been printing anything abrasive (including matte filaments, glow-in-the-dark, wood fill, carbon fiber fill, glass fill, nylon, etc.) then it very well might actually be 0.5-0.6 mm or even worse, and could cause this sort of artifact.